# LINUX Shell script to convert rows to multiple columns

Tags: linux, shell, unix, awk, nawk

Shell script to convert rows to multiple columns

input CSV file:

```
Driver Id,Driver Name,Measure Names,Measure Values
123,XYZ,Total Offers,10
123,XYZ,Driver Reject,0
123,XYZ,Driver Accept ,4
123,XYZ,Expired Offers,3
123,XYZ,Total Bookings,6
123,XYZ,Rider Cancels,2
123,XYZ,Driver Cancels,0
123,XYZ,Rider No-Show,0
123,XYZ,Completed Rides,4
124,PQR,Total Offers,2
124,PQR,Driver Reject,0
124,PQR,Driver Accept ,1
124,PQR,Expired Offers,1
124,PQR,Total Bookings,1
124,PQR,Rider Cancels,0
124,PQR,Driver Cancels,0
124,PQR,Rider No-Show,0
124,PQR,Completed Rides,1
```

Output Required:

Driver Id,Driver Name,Total Offers,Driver Reject,Driver Accept,Expired Offers,Total Bookings,Rider Cancels,Driver Cancels,Rider No-Show,Completed Rides

```
123,XYZ,10,0,4,3,6,2,0,0,4
124,PQR,2,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1
```

I tried with awk but it gives incorrect result.

```
awk -F\, '
    BEGIN{
        P["Total Offers"]="%s;%s;%s;;;;;;;;;\n"
       P["Driver Reject"]="%s;%s;;%s;;;;;;;;\n"
       P["Driver Accept"]="%s;%s;;;%s;;;;;;;\n"
      P["Expired Offers"]="%s;%s;;;;%s;;;;;;\n"
      P["Total Bookings"]="%s;%s;;;;;%s;;;;;\n"     
       P["Rider Cancels"]="%s;%s;;;;;;%s;;;;\n"
      P["Driver Cancels"]="%s;%s;;;;;;;%s;;;\n"     
       P["Rider No-Show"]="%s;%s;;;;;;;;%s;;\n"     
     P["Completed Rides"]="%s;%s;;;;;;;;;%s;\n" 
        }                         
    FNR==1{
        print "Driver Id,Driver Name,Total Offers,Driver Reject,Driver Accept,Expired Offers,Total Bookings,Rider Cancels,Driver Cancels,Rider No-Show,Completed Rides"
        next
        }
    {
        printf(P[$3],$1,$2,$4)
        }
    ' sample1.csv
```

could somebody please assist me or show me any other method to implement this.
Thanks in Advance

Comment: are the lines always sorted by `Driver Id,Driver Name` ?

Comment: not necessarily

Answer (score 0):

Considering your Input_file is same as shown sample and if you don't care of about output sequence should be as input then following may help you in same.

```
awk -F, 'FNR>1{a[$1,$2]=a[$1,$2]?a[$1,$2] FS $NF:$NF} END{for(i in a){print i FS a[i]}}' SUBSEP=","   Input_file
```

Answer (score 0):

Below one takes care of order of output as well as missing value, if there's any

```
awk '
     BEGIN{
       FS=OFS=SUBSEP=","; 
     }
     FNR==1{
        printf("%s%s%s",$1,OFS,$2);
        next
     }
     {
      if(!(($1,$2) in tmp)){
        usr[++u] = $1 OFS $2
        tmp[$1,$2]
      }
      if(!($3 in tmp)){
        names[++n] = $3;
        tmp[$3]
        printf("%s%s",OFS,$3)
      }
       arr[$1,$2,$3] = $4
     }
     END{
       print ""
       for(u=1; u in usr; u++){
           printf("%s", usr[u]);
           for(n=1; n in names; n++){
               indexkey = usr[u] SUBSEP names[n]
               printf("%s%s",OFS, (indexkey in arr) ? arr[indexkey]:"")
           }
           print ""
       }
     }
    ' infile
```

**Explanation:**

- `FS=OFS=SUBSEP=",";` - Set field separator, output field separator and built-in variable subsep to comma, in current program atleast atleast OFS and SUBSEP should be same, because I used it access array `indexkey = usr[u] SUBSEP names[n]`, so if you got any other input field separator (say pipe) then make `FS="|"; OFS=SUBSEP=","`
- `FNR==1{
          printf("%s%s%s",$1,OFS,$2);
          next
  }`
  If first line, then print first 2 fields and go to next line
- `if(!(($1,$2) in tmp)){
          usr[++u] = $1 OFS $2
          tmp[$1,$2]
        }`
   Since you want ordered output, contiguous (in order) array (`usr`) is used in this program. `tmp` is array, where as index being `$1` and `$2`, `usr` is array, where index being variable `u`, value being `$1` and `$2`, `if(!(($1,$2) in tmp))` takes care of if doesn't exist before.
- `if(!($3 in tmp)){
          names[++n] = $3;
          tmp[$3]
          printf("%s%s",OFS,$3)
        }`
   Similarly like above, `names` array is contiguous, value being `$3`
- `arr[$1,$2,$3] = $4` array `arr` key being 3 fields, `$1,$2,$3` and value being `$4`
- Finally in `END` block loop through `usr` and `names` array, build indexkey and print array value, if indexkey exists in array `arr`

Input :

```
$ cat infile
Driver Id,Driver Name,Measure Names,Measure Values
123,XYZ,Total Offers,10
123,XYZ,Driver Reject,0
123,XYZ,Driver Accept ,4
123,XYZ,Expired Offers,3
123,XYZ,Total Bookings,6
123,XYZ,Rider Cancels,2
123,XYZ,Driver Cancels,0
123,XYZ,Rider No-Show,0
123,XYZ,Completed Rides,4
124,PQR,Total Offers,2
124,PQR,Driver Reject,0
124,PQR,Driver Accept ,1
124,PQR,Expired Offers,1
124,PQR,Total Bookings,1
124,PQR,Rider Cancels,0
124,PQR,Driver Cancels,0
124,PQR,Rider No-Show,0
124,PQR,Completed Rides,1
```

Output:

```
$ awk '
     BEGIN{
       FS=OFS=SUBSEP=","; 
     }
     FNR==1{
        printf("%s%s%s",$1,OFS,$2);
        next
     }
     {
      if(!(($1,$2) in tmp)){
        usr[++u] = $1 OFS $2
        tmp[$1,$2]
      }
      if(!($3 in tmp)){
        names[++n] = $3;
        tmp[$3]
        printf("%s%s",OFS,$3)
      }
       arr[$1,$2,$3] = $4
     }
     END{
       print ""
       for(u=1; u in usr; u++){
           printf("%s", usr[u]);
           for(n=1; n in names; n++){
               indexkey = usr[u] SUBSEP names[n]
               printf("%s%s",OFS, (indexkey in arr) ? arr[indexkey]:"")
           }
           print ""
       }
     }
    ' infile
Driver Id,Driver Name,Total Offers,Driver Reject,Driver Accept ,Expired Offers,Total Bookings,Rider Cancels,Driver Cancels,Rider No-Show,Completed Rides
123,XYZ,10,0,4,3,6,2,0,0,4
124,PQR,2,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1
```

Comment: Thanks Akshay...it works good in above file...but when i check it on csv input file then it doesnot give desired result

Comment: The input which you provided is csv file only

Comment: yes, it works for small file and not for large file like below.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B4gv_Iku88JxOEdWeUl3X1JHcWc/view?usp=sharing

Could you pls check it once

Comment: @user2207709 your file got `\r` char, just before `FNR==1` please paste `{ gsub(/\r/,"") }` or else correct your input file using `dos2unix`

Answer (score 0):

if the rows are not ordered in the required fields you have to use an associative array.

```
$ awk -F, -v cols='Total Offers,Driver Reject,Driver Accept ,Expired Offers,Total Bookings,Rider Cancels,Driver Cancels,Rider No-Show,Completed Rides' '
   BEGIN {n=split(cols,f)} 
   NR>1  {k=$1 FS $2; keys[k]; a[k,$3]=$4} 
   END   {for(k in keys) 
             {printf "%s", k; 
              for(i=1;i<=n;i++) printf "%s%d", FS,+a[k,f[i]]; 
              print ""}}' file

124,PQR,2,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1
123,XYZ,10,0,4,3,6,2,0,0,4
```

this will take care if any of the measure rows are missing

ps. Note that "Driver Accept " has a trailing space, which I kept.